# When making Vegan Carnitas, BBQ, & etc., is canned green jackfruit superior to fresh green jackfruit? What about frozen?

Tags: substitutions, vegan, vegetarian, dairy-free

weI have seen a lot of debate regarding the use of green/young jackfruit as a meat substitute in vegan cooking, but the opinions i find on the subject are all simply reading copy, or incorporating third and fourth party quotes or talking points into their article.

Which one renders the best texture? Why does that form have a better texture?

Are there any other pros and cons of each option?

Comment: Are you interested in general pros and cons, or really just texture? I think there are some practical difficulties with fresh green jackfruit too.

Comment: i was hoping for some discussion regarding the pros and cons of each form.